# How to use Gzip in Webservices Response C#?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I am calling webservices from javascript,i want response back in gzip but presently my response is not gzip. can any on help me out...

edit: this is the code i use

```
$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "wsDashboard.asmx/" + 'Banner_GetAll',

    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (response) {
        response = response.d;
        if (!response.isSucceeded) {
            j.Alert(response.message, "Error");
            return;
        }
        var result = response.result;

        var arrBanner = [];
        for (var index = 0; index < result.length; index++) {
            var newBanner = new Banner(result[index].Id, result[index].BannerName, result[index].Url, result[index].HyperLink);
            arrBanner.push(newBanner);
        }
        if (callback) callback(arrBanner);


    }
});
```

i have configured iis to give responses in gzip all other contents are comming Gziped except for the web service response i would like to compress that too (the response is given in json) the request header contains header accept encoding Gzip

Comment: Hello Mahipat, it's helpful if you can show some code/let people know what you've tried so that they might be better able to help you to solve your specific problem.

Comment: Thanks for your first question. You'll need to add some more information as to what you're calling on the server and what you've tried so far. http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 0):

Either you allow it in IIS level or by code check the GZipStream class

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx

I would go for a change in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the client is not stating that is accepts GZip, you need to do this in the Accept-Encoding header, e.g.

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate